# Static Application Switcher is empty after show dekstop

Tags: unity, application-switcher

I'm using the Static Application Switcher to configure my <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to cycle through all applications not grouped. So far so good.

Then I press <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to "hide all normal windows" (show desktop). This setting is from *Keyboard* -> *Shortcuts* -> *Navigation*. This also works

BUT

After hiding all normal windows has been activated and I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> nothing comes up. I suspect they have been hidden so well that the Application Switcher does no longer see them.

Anyone know if this can be fixed through settings somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because that plugin works by default on "active" windows.
You should consider associating <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> shortcut to ALL windows.

Give it a try:

- CCSM/Application Switcher/Association tab.
- Get rid of Next window / Previous window keyboard shortcuts and apply them to
- Next window (All windows) / Previous window (All windows).

Hope this helps.